# How to assign new Class object through factory method but in a "generic" way?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a class where I can pass optional parameters and through a factory method it assigns the values to the corresponding class attributes.

But I cannot access in a "generic" way any attributes on the class.

```
this[key] = object[key];
```

Is there a way to do it?

This is my object assignement:

```
p1: Person = new Person({ name: 'John Doe' });
p2: Person = new Person({ age: 2, height: 180 });
```

This is my Person class:

```
export class Person {
  name: string = '';
  age: number = 0;
  height: number = 0;

  constructor(data: Object) {
    this.factory(data);
  }

  factory(object: Object) {
    for (const key in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this[key] = object[key]; // <-- HERE IS MY PROBLEM
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I put my code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsxr1w?file=src/app/person.model.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an elegant solution for this. Add an indexer and use a more concrete parameter type. Look at this:

```
export class Person {
  name: string = '';
  age: number = 0;
  height: number = 0;

  [key: string]: any;

  constructor(data: Partial<Person>) {
    this.factory(data);
  }

  factory(object: Partial<Person>) {
    for (const key in object) {
      this[key] = object[key];
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**: That should work even without indexer:

```
factory(object: Partial<Person>) {
  Object.assign(this, object);
}
```

Comment: WOW, thats amazing! Can you explain whats this Partial means?

Comment: `Partial` is a [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html). This constructs a type with all properties of `Type` set to optional. You can pass in one, all, or none of the properties of the `Type`. It gives you way more type safety and ergonomics than `Object`.

Comment: Any tips on [key: string]: any
XD
I don't even know what to search in order to understand this statement

Comment: You use that to make your type an indexable type. You define the type of the index key (in this case string) and the type it expects (here any). But as I mentioned in the update: Using Object.assign should get the job done without the index definition.